# Mocking not working with pytest and flexmock

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, flexmock

I'm trying to use pytest fixtures to mock calls to `open()` and then reset it on test teardown, but for some reason the mock is not applied in the test function.

Here's a sample of what I have:

```py
# tests.py
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def mock_open(request):
    mock = flexmock(sys.modules['__builtin__'])
    mock.should_call('open')
    m = (mock.should_receive('open')
        .with_args('/tmp/somefile')
        .and_return(read=lambda: 'file contents'))
    request.addfinalizer(lambda: m.reset())

def test_something(mock_open):
    ret = function_to_test()
    ret[1]()  # This actually uses the original open()
```

And, in case it matters, here's what the `function_to_test()` looks like:

```py
# some_module.py
def function_to_test():
    def inner_func():
        open('/tmp/somefile').read()   # <-- I want this call mocked
        # More code ...
    return (True, inner_func)
```

This also happens if I use xUnit-style `setup_module()`/`teardown_module()` functions. But if I put the mocking code within the test function itself (which I obviously don't want to do), then it works fine.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a full self-contained example and include the versions of libraries you are using?  I haven't used flexmock but your fixture looks good on first side.  When i tried to run it i got ``and_return() got an unexpected keyword argument 'read'``.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about using [`mock`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock)?

---

tests.py:

```
import mock # import unittest.mock (Python 3.3+)
import pytest

from some_module import function_to_test

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def mock_open(request):
    m = mock.patch('__builtin__.open', mock.mock_open(read_data='file content'))
    m.start()
    request.addfinalizer(m.stop)

def test_something(mock_open):
    ret = function_to_test()
    assert ret[1]() == 'file content'
```

some_module.py:

```
def function_to_test():
    def inner_func():
        return open('/tmp/somefile').read()
    return True, inner_func
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try, but I really prefer flexmock's API. If I can't figure it out, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @imiric, Did you figure it out how to do it with flexmock?

Comment: Sorry for the delay with accepting your answer. I don't remember getting this to work with `flexmock`, but these days I do indeed use `mock` exclusively, and as you correctly pointed out, it's pretty straightforward to do. Thanks again!